# Composition of functions and the composition is unknown.

Tags: calculus

$$g(x)=x+3$$

$$f(g(x)) = x^{2}+1 $$

How to find the effect of f on x?

What I did was changing the variable $$y=x+3 $$

So $$f(x) = f(y-3) = y^{2} -6y+10 $$

Then I changed the variable from y to x and got the correct answer but I can't understand why it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you get $f(x)=f(y-3)=y^2-6y+10?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually you have some little bugs in your writing above

let $y = x + 3$, so $x = y - 3$ 
but in the following, you'd better write like this:
$f(g(x)) = f(x+3) = f(y)$, 
and $x^2 + 1 = (y-3)^2-1$, 
BETTER NOT OMIT THESE DETAILS

now we have 
$f(x+3) = f(y)$
and 
$x^2 + 1 = (y-3)^2+1$

since $f(g(x)) = f(x+3) = x^2 + 1$

we obtain $f(y) = (y-3)^2 + 1 = y^2 - 6x + 10$

More precisely, the function is like this:

$f(\cdot) = (\cdot)^2 - 6 (\cdot) + 10$

Comment: @El Chapo  Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you familiar with mathjax formatting?

Comment: @El Chapo, well, thank you, now I know it is just same as Tex editing.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is just a variable.

$f$ is a function that maps R to R.  We want to express $f(x) = $(something in terms of x).

But $x$ is just a variable.  We can express $f(y) = $(the same thing in terms of y).  So ....

Okay.  Try this:

$g(x) = x + 3$

Let's call $x = x_{\text{old}}$ and let's call $g(x) = x_{\text{new}}$.

So $ x_{\text{new}} = g(x) = x + 3= x_{\text{old}} + 3$ so $x_{\text{old}} = x_{\text{new}} - 3$

Now we know that $f(g(x)) = f(x_{\text{new}})= x^2 + 1 = x_{\text{old}}^2 + 1$.  But what is $f$ in terms of $x_{\text{new}}$?

$f(x_{\text{new}})= x_{\text{old}}^2 + 1 = ( x_{\text{new}} - 3)^2 + 1 =  x_{\text{new}}^2 - 6 x_{\text{new}} + 10$

Okay, so $x_{\text{new}}$ and $x_{\text{old}}$... what's the difference? At this point they are just variables.

$f(anything) = anything^2 - 6anything + 10$.

So $f(x) = x^2 - 6x + 10$.

Okay, ... but next time we'll just use $g(x) = y$

Answer (score 0):

As you have put $y=g(x)=x+3$,

Then $f(g(x))=x^2+1=f(y)$. But since $x=y-3$, we get

$f(y)=(y-3)^2+1=y^2-6y+10$.

Now, since $y$ can take any value, as a variable, that's why instead of $y$ we can use any variable, like $t$,$s$,$v$ or even $x$. This doesn't matter at all!